# Redirecting call from a Twilio to Microsoft Teams

Tags: twilio, microsoft-teams, sip, twilio-api

I am trying to understand if there is a way we can transfer/redirect active call from `Twilio` to `Microsoft Teams` user.

Incoming call to `Twilio` will be a SIP audio call.
`MS Teams` will act as `SIP Gateway/Server` which can receive call from `Twilio` and Teams user will see the incoming call.

I was reading few of the articles on Twilio:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/call-forwarding-java-spark
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/call-transfer

Does Twilio and MS Teams supports this feature using the APIs?

Answer (score 1):

As you will have read in the [SIP trunking call transfer](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/call-transfer) article, you can absolutely transfer a SIP call from Twilio to another SIP endpoint.

I have no experience of that with MS Teams, but it appears that [you can make SIP calls to Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/direct-routing-protocols-sip). Though some of the documentation points out that [you may need specific hardware that supports Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/sip-gateway-plan).

Comment: thanks for the post, I have read the MS document for SIP Gateway but I thought it is just for the listed telephone devices. In my case I want to transfer from the Twilio server to the MS gateway. But this can be the approach I guess but not exactly sure if it will work.

Comment: I presume (though I am no expert) that if there is a SIP endpoint that you can send a SIP call to, then you might be able to connect. I'm not the best resource for this though, I'm afraid. I'd recommend speaking to Microsoft support to see what they can tell you about their SIP access.

Comment: For the information that is available from the links it looks like direct routing need to be implemented using the SBC but thing is that I want to have the control to whom (the teams user) the call need to be forwarded. I am not sure at this point if there is any other option then using SBC. May be: have the SIP endpoint address and the credential of the Teams SIP Gateway and configure in the Twilio trunk, but not sure it Teams works that way. Yes Microsoft support may help in this case.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the Twilio side. If we need to transfer call to another third party SIP Server which is out side the Twilio infrastructure. Do we need to configure that third party SIP server as a new Trunk? If so, I am not able to find the page where we can configure new SIP server as a SIP Trunk. Please point to the Twilio document which describe this process. Also call transfer (refer) document https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/call-transfer does not show any code samples how the transfer is done, please point to sample code that would be helpful.

Comment: There aren't code samples as the process of transferring a call is normally handled by a PBX. In this case, your PBX should send a SIP REFER message to Twilio with a `Refer-To` header that tells Twilio the new SIP address to transfer the call to.

Comment: @User7723337 - Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or still looking for any help.

Comment: I think it is pretty much clear on the MS side that it will be through SBC (no other way I found). I am not sure how it works on the Twilio side how the REFER need to sent to the Twilio. As philnash said PBX need to submit the REFER, but I am not sure how the PBX comes into picture. Incoming call is received inside the Twilio (using Twilio SDK/APIs) and I was expecting Twilio API to transfer the call.

Comment: Oh, I though you were using a SIP trunk. If you need to redirect a call to a SIP address you can [update the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#update-a-call-resource) with the [`<Sip>` TwiML element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip).